# How to insert code from Ruby into HTML?

Tags: html, ruby

Is it possible to insert Ruby into HTML, the same way you can insert Javascript or CSS into HTML.

Comment: The proper answer on that question is: no, this is not possible.

Comment: Its not possible in the same way. Because javascript and CSS are interpreted by the Browser of the user. But you can use ruby to construct html layouts with erb. But this happens on your server, before sending the result to the client user. (Obs: CSS is not a programming language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at Opal: http://opalrb.org/

There is no way to run Ruby natively in the browser. It has to be converted to JS at some point, either when the page is loaded or as a preprocess task when your site is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

From the client side, it's completly impossible, I don't know any browser which could interpret directly Ruby.

But assuming you are still a beginner, I figured you are searching for that:
Erb templating in ROR:

```
<h1>Listing Books</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Summary</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= book.title %></td>
    <td><%= book.content %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Show", book %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_book_path(book) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Remove", book, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to "New book", new_book_path %
```

Doc: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

This is server side templating, it's mean the HTML page will be generate on the server side, and send it's as simple HTML page, without any Ruby on it.

If not, why do you want to use Ruby from the client?
Like someone notice, you have some preprocessor who can compile Ruby into Js (even if it's seems a little useless for me, but it's only my opinion)

Comment: What does server-side template have in common with client-side scripting?

Comment: Do client side Ruby is impossible, the closest way to using it is server side templating.

Comment: It's obviously impossible from the client side... So I gave the cloest way to use Ruby on View, Templating from server side. Is it that stupid for have a minus one?

Comment: @JulienLeray. Specify the differences, or your answer will remain misleading. The OP might not even know what a templating system is.

Answer (score 0):

I remember at some point there was experiment with Ruby + NaCl for chrome.

It looks like there is [nacl port for ruby 2.0](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/naclports/+/master/ports/ruby). That is closest you can get to running ruby in browser. look for [IRB chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ruby-irb/mdoifndjjoblccpefkbdicgahkbbcfdk?hl=en) that uses ruby NaCl for chrome as a proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on, whether you have a server behind or not.
If you have a ruby server behind (f.e. you use Rails), than you could use erb tags in the html (because the server will render your 'template' and produce a 'finished' html code).

If you have a php server behind, than you will use  tags inside the html (again template rendering is happened on the server side).

Another solution would be to use client side template engines, where the client gets the whole data + the template and produces the 'finished' html code. For this kind of rendering, look at handlebarsjs or underscorejs template.